# Switching the Monitor the Panel Displays in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-11.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.04, and I recently upgraded to a dual-monitor setup. The panel displays on my laptops screen, while the larger aftermarket screen remains empty (no panels). I was wondering if it was possible to switch which monitor the panel is displayed in. This would be useful seeing as my laptops monitor is no longer my primary screen.

Comment: Switching to 11.10 seems to have fixed this issue.